# Should the Help Center sidebar also match the theme color of the website?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, help-center

While checking out the Help Center, I noticed something that I think in my opinion should be slightly changed.

Should the sidebar of the Help Center (The box which holds all of the questions and topics in the Help Center) be changed to the website's theme color?

[image: Help Center Sidebar Screenshot]

Right now, the sidebar looks like we're in Stack Overflow.

The reason why I think this should be changed is because I think this would make the site look better for some users.

But of course, I think this is mostly on people's opinions, and that's the reason we should discuss about this minor change.

How do you people think of it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I have just returned from a break of Meta Stack Exchange, and unlucky me have I not checked the older questions! (Oops!)